# How to increment Ruby variable in erb template?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop, increment

My problem is I have a for-loop written in Javascript with some Ruby code inside :

```
<% i = 0 %>
for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
   alert("<%= i %>");
   <% i += 1 %>
}
```

And I always have an alert with "0" written in.
How can I increment my `i` variable correctly ?

Comment: what is `array`? and how is it defined?

Comment: array contains 6 strings : var array = ["january","march","may","july","september","october"];

Comment: its from ruby or JS?

Comment: It is a Javascript array and I have my 6 alerts, but with 0 printed.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that there is no loop occurring when the template is being run through ERB. You have a javascript loop which is not executed at all when run through ERB - it is being passed over as plain text and ERB is executing/substituting only when it encounters `<% .. %>` or `<%= .. %>`

Processed by ERB

```
<% i = 0 %>
for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    alert("<%= i %>");
    <% i += 1 %>
}
```

becomes the following by the time it reaches the browser:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    alert("0");
}
```

So when you iterate over the array in JS you are alerting the constant `"0"` for each iteration. You want to write this in your ERB template:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    alert(i);
}
```

Remember, ERB is subsituting in appropriate content from the back end (your database) and has no knowledge of or interaction with the JS that ends up in the front end (in the browser).